# Unable to boot to windows

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

Context:

Recently I've bought an SSD. Before that I had 2 HDDs; one being a 500GB drive with a W7 installation, and another 320GB Drive containing two partitions, one of which for storage (NTFS) and another to hold a linux mint installation (Which I'm currently on).

When the SSD arrived I set up another W7 installation. Once this was fully set-up, I wanted to format the 500GB drive to use it for storage. I've done this today, and as a result wiped the windows loader from my system.

Ideally, what I would like is for the windows boot manager to be on the SSD, and a grub installation on the 320GB drive.

Then I'd like the system to boot to the 320GB drive, and give options to load the Windows boot manager, or boot to linux.

Since the windows drive cannot be booted to, when running a W7 disc and using CLI I get the error "element not found" when attempting to use "recboot /fixboot". using /scanos does find my W7 installation however. I've also set the W7 partition as active and rebooted, but had the same results.

I've also attempted using boot-repair, however my system still cannot boot to windows. My current boot summary is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7299901/).

My current grub boot menu just lists the mint installations.

How can I fix this to include a windows boot loader?

@terdon:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
  No volume groups found
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo update-grub`. That will attempt to detect your operating systems and will update your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. Does that fix things?

Comment: Afraid not ^^..

Comment: Umm, are you sure you still have a Win install? You said you formatted the drive it was on. What makes you think it's still there?

Comment: For sure yes, I formatted the older installation from the HDD but still have the newer install on the SSD. Windows recovery doesn't detect it, but the recboot /ScanOS command within recovery does find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having was caused by a windows installation without a boot loader.

When attempting to fix this using Windows Recovery, the Windows installation could not be found because I had a separate hard drive with a Linux installation running in the system.

When I unplugged this Linux HDD leaving just the windows HDD plugged in, the recovery could then successfully detect the Windows installation and fix the boot issues.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simplest by far to hook up the SSD by itself and get it booting properly first, before adding the other drives and GRUB to the mix. Try `recboot /fixmbr` if you haven't already. Ensure that the partition is flagged as bootable. Do a `chkdsk C: /f /r` to check for errors.

Once you have it booting correctly, add the other drives and try updating GRUB again. It should add an entry with a simple `chainloader` command that just hands over the rest of the boot process to the Win7 bootloader.

Comment: I was attempting to do this at the same time really. I finally decided to try the windows recovery with the SSD as the only drive hooked up, this allowed the recovery to detect the windows installtion; before with the other drives also hooked up it would just instantly display that no installations were found, maybe the linux partitions triggered this? Anyhow, I was then able to repair the windows bootmgr, and thus repair grub successfully.

Comment: In a sense, yes.  Windows utils - particularly Windows recovery/boot utils - often assume that there is only one bootable device available, and will fail if others are found (even though GRUB would see this as a perfectly valid configuration).  Thanks, glad it's working.